# Inline URL markup does not accept accented characters in the URL

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Example:

- This person.  (Edit post to see that "This person" should be a link)
- The [non-accented form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genevieve_Bujold) does work, though.  (Luckily, Wikipedia does a redirect)
- Using the long form from the popup [does work with the accent, though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genevi%C3%A8ve_Bujold).
- As seen in my comment to this question, short-form *does* work in comments.
- As seen [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7605895#7605895), it also works in chat.

So..  At the very least, it's inconsistent.

Comment: [Testing comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneviève_Bujold) **EDIT:** Short form _does_ work in comments.  Interesting bug.

Comment: I use is.gd or some other shortener for links like this. Not optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use URL encoding for non-ASCII characters such as accented letters:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genevi%C3%A8ve_Bujold
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genevi%C3%A8ve_Bujold

Both Chrome and Firefox encode the accented letter when I copy-paste the whole URL from the URL bar. If you use the hyperlink tool of the markdown editor and enter the URL with the accented letter, the tool inserts the encoded URL.

Given that most natural methods to insert a URL result in something that works, I'm guessing a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) here.

[Markdown renderer doesn't accept é or ö in links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/markdown-renderer-doesnt-accept-e-or-o-in-links) on the main meta was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) when the markdown editor hyperlink insertion tool became capable of translating non-ASCII characters into their URL encoding.

Comment: I did copy/paste from Firefox, though...  The weirder thing is that it _does_ work in comments.